# ASP.NET WebApi not receiving post data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to receive some string and binary data using WebApi. I have created a controller this way:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(byte[] buffer)
    {
        // Some code goes here
    }
```

Here's the routtings:

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CuscarD95B",
        routeTemplate: "D95B/{controller}",
        defaults: new { buffer = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { controller = @"Cuscar" }
```

Now when I try to post some data, buffer is always byte[0] (zero length array). No data is being passed to the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are ever struggling with deserializing a body, try and do it manually to see if you are actually sending it correctly.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post()
{
    string body = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for that little gem. I am having no end of problems passing raw text in the body (via Fiddler2) and getting `FromBody` to see it, but your snippet saved the day. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

We passed Json object by HttpPost method, and parse it in dynamic object. it works fine. this is sample code:

```
ajaxPost:
...
Content-Type: application/json,
data: {"name": "Jack", "age": "12"}
...
```

Web API:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DoJson2(dynamic data)
{
    string name = data.name;
    int age = data.age;

    return name;
}
```

If there is complext object type, you need to parse the dynamic type by using:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< YourObjectType >(data.ToString());
```

A complex data content sample is here, it includes array and dictionary object:

```
{"AppName":"SamplePrice","AppInstanceID":"100","ProcessGUID":"072af8c3-482a-4b1c‌​-890b-685ce2fcc75d","UserID":"20","UserName":"Jack","NextActivityPerformers":{"39‌​c71004-d822-4c15-9ff2-94ca1068d745":[{"UserID":10,"UserName":"Smith"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to post a byte[] in my request body, and the value was successfully model bound.  Was the content-type set?  Note that simple string is considered to be valid JSON here, and so it should work if your request's content-type is set to application/json...

Having said that, you can simply have your POST method that expects a string from the body instead of a byte[] and set the content-type to be application/json:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string buffer)
{
    // Some code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maggie, I tried setting content-type to application/json but buffer is null :|.

Comment: Can share your byte[] content that you are trying to send?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to send `byte[]` to webApi, but what you can do is to pass the binary data as `Base64 string` to your controller and then convert the `base64 string` to the `byte[]`.

Comment: hmm, is it possible to send just string to webapi? not xml or json, some unstructured string data. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any working sample of passing a plain string param to ApiController via POST? I can't find any. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/).
Looks like we need to create custom MediaTypeFormatter to achieve primitive type deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the HttpPostedFileBase without `[FromBody]` ?

```
public void Post(HttpPostedFileBase buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I was using a string array and it would always come through null or I would get an exception about an improperly formatted request. I added the annotation `[FromUri]` in my method parameters then it worked. To give a little more context, my controller method looked like this before:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyControllerName(List<string> id)
```

After:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyControllerName([FromUri] List<string> id)
```