# I'm not getting any data in the api controller when posting the base64 data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My ajax call:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',     
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' },     
    url: myURL,     
    data:  { "data": content },    
    dataType: 'json'    
})
```

My api controller is

```
[Route("upload")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public string upload([FromBody]byte[] data) {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Can you actually break into the method when you do the call?

Comment: Yes i can break , but when i see the data variable it is null

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284460/asp-net-webapi-not-receiving-post-data

I think that if you set your data to string, you will get the Base64 encoded string, and should be able to decode it in C#

Comment: Reformatted the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I forgot to mention. This is fixed. Coincidentally I used the same approach @AndreiNeagu mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent the data as the string and converted to Base64 on the controller. It worked for me.

It seems there is one more way to do it that is writing a custom MediaTypeFormatter.